# How can I read JSON sublevels with rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am new to rails and I am trying to read a JSON uri. I can read the information but I don´t know how to access the sublevels of the json file. I am doing this:

```
resp = Net::HTTP.get_response(URI.parse(uri))

parsedresp = JSON.parse(resp.body)
```

I get as a answer the follow information:

```
{"success"=>true, "data"=>[{"id"=>1, "public_id"=>1, "company_id"=>60861, "user_id"=>{"value"=>74138, "name"=>"Daniel Galvao"}}]}
```

When I use `parsedresp["data"]` I get the information:

```
[{"id"=>1, "public_id"=>1, "company_id"=>60861, "user_id"=>{"value"=>74138, "name"=>"Daniel Galvao"}}]
```

My problem is that I don't know how to get the information "name"=>"Daniel Galvao" to store in the DB. Can someone help me? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value of `parsedresp["data"]` is an array, so to get its value, you have to pass it an index (`[0]` for the first and only element):

```
parsedresp["data"][0]
#=> {"id"=>1, "public_id"=>1, "company_id"=>60861, "user_id"=>{"value"=>74138, "name"=>"Daniel Galvao"}}
```

To get the user data, pass this hash the `user_id` hash key:

```
parsedresp["data"][0]["user_id"]
#=> {"value"=>74138, "name"=>"Daniel Galvao"}
```

If you want to get the name of the user, then:

```
parsedresp["data"][0]["user_id"]["name"]
#=> "Daniel Galvao"
```

Comment: You're welcome! Pls mark this as the answer if you are happy with it.